# How to break up a percent increase over time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have a number, $x$, and every $12$ hours it's multiplied by $1.2.$ How would I multiply it every $5$ minutes so that after $12$ hours it's increased by the same amount as the first example?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

After $5$ minutes, the number becomes $ax$.

After $10$ minutes, the number becomes $a^2x$.

After $15$ minutes, the number becomes $a^3x$.

After $5n$ minutes, the number becomes $a^nx$ $(n\in\mathbb{Z^+})$.

$12$ hours is $720$ minutes or $5\times 144$ minutes. For $n=144$, can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

After 5 minutes, the number is $1.2x$. After 10 minutes, the number is $1.2^2x$. After $5n$ minutes, the number is $1.2^nx$.

After 12 hours, the number has increased by $0.2x$. We want to find $0.2x=m^{144}x-x$. Solving gives $m=\sqrt[144]{1.2}$.